# send anonymous usage information to mcafee(recommended) is it ok to check this option?

Tags: windows-8, anti-virus

While installing McAfee, I get a message `send anonymous usage information to mcafee(recommended)`. Is it OK to check this option or should I uncheck it?

Answer (score 0):

It should be exactly what it sounds - you should be able to find details in EULA if you have the time to read it. However it is still going to be sending information about your machine, so if you are not OK with that, disable/leave unchecked - it's optional for a reason ;)

Choosing not to send(...) will not affect the protection provided by application.